# update view after every iteration: plotly.js addTraces loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plotly

The $scope.graphPlots2 holds all the traces to be drawn.

the layout:
[image]

```
 for(c=0; c < $scope.graphPlots2.length; c++ ){
              if(c == 0){
                Plotly.newPlot(graphRender, [$scope.graphPlots2[c]], $scope.layout2);
              }else{
                Plotly.addTraces(graphRender, $scope.graphPlots2[c]);
              }
 }
```

It does not throw error, but view(graph) is not updated(show new added traces) until end of loop. I'd like to see each trace appear as added.

graphRender.data after loop finishes:

```
 [
    {
        "name": "DOC.1050 - Weight - ",
        "x": [
            "2011-01-01 00:01:00",
            "2011-02-01 00:01:00",
            "2011-03-01 00:01:00",
            "2011-04-01 00:01:00",
            "2011-05-01 00:01:00",
            "2011-05-27 00:01:00"
        ],
        "y": [
            103,
            102,
            221.7,
            102.7,
            99.8,
            108
        ],
        "type": "scatter",
        "visible": true,
        "line": {
            "shape": "linear"
        },
        "mode": "lines",
        "uid": "db720d"
    },
    {
        "name": "DOC.1050 - blood pressure - ",
        "x": [
            "2011-01-01 00:01:00",
            "2011-02-01 00:01:00",
            "2011-03-04 00:01:00",
            "2011-04-01 00:01:00",
            "2011-05-01 00:01:00",
            "2011-05-25 00:01:00"
        ],
        "y": [
            9000,
            19980,
            8800,
            8700,
            8000,
            7500
        ],
        "type": "scatter",
        "visible": true,
        "line": {
            "shape": "linear"
        },
        "mode": "lines",
        "uid": "4631f2"
    },
    {
        "name": "DOC.4258 - Weight - ",
        "x": [
            "2011-01-02 00:01:00",
            "2011-02-02 00:01:00",
            "2011-03-02 00:01:00",
            "2011-04-02 00:01:00",
            "2011-05-02 00:01:00"
        ],
        "y": [
            299.8,
            202.7,
            201,
            204,
            201.7
        ],
        "type": "scatter",
        "visible": true,
        "line": {
            "shape": "linear"
        },
        "mode": "lines",
        "uid": "23afcd"
    },
    {
        "name": "DOC.47007 - Weight - ",
        "x": [
            "2011-01-03 00:01:00",
            "2011-03-03 00:01:00",
            "2011-03-20 00:01:00",
            "2011-04-05 00:01:00",
            "2011-05-01 00:01:00",
            "2011-05-27 00:01:00"
        ],
        "y": [
            92,
            68,
            92.7,
            79.8,
            181.7,
            41
        ],
        "type": "scatter",
        "visible": true,
        "line": {
            "shape": "linear"
        },
        "mode": "lines",
        "uid": "64f6fb"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow using a foreach solved the issue...

```
        $scope.graphPlots2.forEach(function(trace, i) {
           if(i==0){
             Plotly.newPlot('graphRender', [trace], $scope.layout2);
           }else{
              setTimeout(function() {
                Plotly.addTraces('graphRender', trace);
              }, 0);
           }
        });
```